# PHP thumbnail image

Tags: php, thumbnails

I have creating PHP application which takes images with any height and width. It creates 2 different images as follows,
1: thumbnail image (small image) with size 130x130 
2: preview image (big image) with 600x400.

How can we decide the height and width of thumbnail & preview image from the height and width of input image?

I have few images with sizes 100x1600, 1024x1024, 316x360.

If i decrease/increase the size of input image most of the time, either any image is streched or compact.

What is the way to find the desired height and width so that thumbnail & preview image looks good?

Comment: clarify the question.. Do u want to create 2 type of thumbnails keeping aspect ratio? Provide us your syntax and then only we can help you.. we are not magicians..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need ratio:

```
$src_ratio = $src_width/$src_height; //ratio of source
$ratio = $width/$height; //ratio of preview
if ($ratio < $src_ratio) $height = $width/$src_ratio;
else $width = $height*$src_ratio+1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you should use [getimagesize()](http://ru.php.net/getimagesize)
 function to get the original size of the image file...

Comment: I have already used it. My question is how can i find out height & width of thumbnail & preview image. I have images with  160x1600, 1024x1024, 316x360 and so on.

Comment: according to the task you're creating a app that takes any image and **creates** thumbs and previews, you should know the sizes, it's impossible to create without knowing the sizes...

Answer (score 0):

You need the [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) function.

```
$attributes = getimagesize($thumbfilename);
var_dump($attributes);
```